# How to determine which physical port is connected to which tty path?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, serial-port

I have a device (An NVIDIA Jetson Nano) with four USB ports. How can I tell which `/dev/tty*` locations are mapped to each of these?

I have gone through many similar questions here and on askUbuntu. I have been trying `lsusb`, `dmesg | grep tty`, `usb-devices`, but quite frankly I don't have a clue what I'm doing with this information.

`lsusb` was the only command I could vaguely understand. By moving a USB dongle from port to port I thought I could determine the bus and device numbers. Until I got to the last port, whereupon I swapped the dongle who's ID I knew with the keyboard that had been in that port for the first three tests, and realized that the device numbers aren't even static. The keyboard had been Bus 001 Device 005 for the first three tests but the same port was Bus 001 Device 010 now that it had the dongle (and the port that had held the dongle had been 009 and was now 011 with the keyboard, so it seemed to just be incrementing). So I don't see how this information is at all useful. Plus, I wouldn't know how to get a device path from the device number even if I trusted these numbers.

`dmesg | grep tty` just lists a few of the available serial ports and does not change when I change the ports that devices are plugged into, so I can't see how to use that to learn anything. I tried repeating this command after playing around with `lsusb`, using the same method of moving the dongle around to the different ports, and now it outputs nothing, even when run as root.

`usb-devices` lists a ton of devices, way more than there's room for physically, and once again does not change its output when the state of the physical port changes.

Overall I really just don't know what I'm doing, so I apologize if I've misused any technical terms here and hope what I'm saying is clear from context. The Device/Port/Adapter/Bus distinctions elude me, so that might be part of why I'm having difficulty googling this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What kind of USB dongles are you connecting to it? USB ports _themselves_ do not have a 'tty' device, as they are not serial ports.

Comment: @user1686 The dongle is a wireless mouse receiver. I was under the impression that you could send serial data through a USB connection as UART provided the other end of the connection has an adaptor. I plan to use pyserial in a python script to send UART data to a black-box with such an adaptor, but I need to know the device path associated with the port on which the external black-box is connected in order to use pyserial. https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html

Comment: Well, yes, actual USB UART serial adapters do show up in /dev under various tty names – but wireless mouse receivers really will not, nor will other USB device types (and not the ports in themselves). Have you tried connecting the actual serial adapter to see how it might be recognized?

Comment: @user1686 Alright, good - then what? `dmesg | grep tty` still gives nothing at all, not sure why it showed something earlier but won't now... also `lsusb` and `usb-devices` still aren't giving information I know how to use. Also - don't all the possible device locations always show up in `/dev/` regardless of whether they're connected to anything or not? E.g. I have a have tty0 through tty63, ttyp0 through ttyp9, etc, etc, way more devices than I imagine are actually in use. I still don't know how to tell where to send my serial data... Thanks again for the help!

Comment: "don't all the possible device locations always show up in /dev/" No, normally they don't. (Not since 15-20 years ago.) The numeric "tty#" devices are always there only because they're all virtual consoles: they have nothing to do with physical UART devices. The "ttyp#" devices are similar (they're an obsolete "pseudo-tty" interface used by xterm/urxvt; modern distros shouldn't have them.) Your USB adapter is none of those; it will only show up in /dev once connected, assuming it is recognized by Linux at all. (But sounds like it's not. What Linux distribution are you running on the machine?)

Comment: @user1686 It's some form of ubuntu for ARM distributed by NVIDIA for the platform - `uname -r` gives `4.9.201-tegra`. So does all this mean that I can potentially e.g. write out the names of all files in /dev/ before and after plugging in the device and take the diff?

Comment: Yes – but does dmesg report the adapter being connected at all (not necessarily as a tty)? At minimum, what is its vendor ID / product ID (those should show up in both lsusb and dmesg, as 4 hex digits each)?

Comment: @user1686 I am not able to see if it shows up in `dmesg` without grepping, there's just too much information and I don't know how to read it. `lsusb` doesn't show the device in question at all, although it does show the mouse dongle as an unnamed `25a7:fa10`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, confirm that your cables are functional. It's surprisingly common for a USB cable to fail at data transmission and you won't be able to tell unless you test it, so don't make assumptions. I went through 4 cables I thought were good before finding one that actually transmitted data in addition to power.

Second, I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but what I ended up getting working was basically a combination of `ls` and `diff` to determine when a new file appeared in `/dev`.

Start with your device unplugged by using `ls /dev > device_names.txt` (or any filepath of your choice instead of device_names.txt) to write all the device names currently available to a file. Next, plug in your device to the port you care about and use `ls /dev | diff - device_names.txt` to get the differences between the current list of device names and the list prior to plugging in your device.

In my case, this revealed my device took `ttyACM0` on that port. I still don't know if this is determined entirely by the device and has nothing to do with the physical port... if this is the case, then the original question makes no sense, but oh well.